# Summing up a data frame according to a column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to present the following data frame per sum of each city:

```
> summary(dat1)
      Date                 City           Sales        
 Min.   :2010-06-18   Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :  667.4  
 1st Qu.:2011-02-18   1st Qu.:18.00   1st Qu.: 1138.6  
 Median :2011-10-28   Median :37.00   Median : 1507.5  
 Mean   :2011-10-29   Mean   :44.26   Mean   : 2065.4  
 3rd Qu.:2012-07-06   3rd Qu.:74.00   3rd Qu.: 2347.1  
 Max.   :2013-03-08   Max.   :99.00   Max.   :47206.6
```

i.e. I would like to find the data frame with corresponding Date X City observations that will present the sum of sales for each city in on each Day.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities for this. To name a few:

1. Function aggregate():

   i) `aggregate(Sales~Date+City, data=df, sum)`

   ii) `aggregate(df$Sales, list(df$Date,df$City), sum)`
2. Function tapply():

   i) `tapply(df$Sales, list(df$Date, df$City), sum)`

Function `tapply()` is especially useful, if you have a large dataset, since aggregate tends to choke on very large data sets, but `tapply()` typically handles these more gracefully. Also, `tapply()` and `aggregate()`generate the output in different formats, and you might want to select the one that is most appropriate for possible furter analyses.

These examples can be tested on a simulated data that is presented below:

```
df<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2014-01-01", "2014-02-01", 
"2014-03-01", "2014-04-01"), class = "factor"), City = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), 
    Sales = c(100, 100, 93, 92, 95, 115, 104, 106, 113, 94, 93, 
    98, 116, 85, 98, 97, 103, 110, 105, 104, 107, 86, 92, 94, 
    106, 115, 112, 92, 103, 100, 101, 97, 95, 110, 103, 92, 91, 
    98, 100, 93, 108, 87, 96, 101, 87, 111, 90, 94, 110, 95, 
    110, 101, 88, 99, 106, 117, 101, 120, 92, 86, 118, 104, 99, 
    89, 103, 102, 121, 99, 106, 99, 107, 105, 109, 110, 112, 
    94, 100, 112)), .Names = c("Date", "City", "Sales"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -78L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You need to change your codes because names of variables are not correct.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the capitalization of the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

See `aggregation` function

```
aggregate(Sales~Date+City, data=dat1, sum)
```

Comment: Is your code correct? I can't get the formula to work this way. Should it not be Sales~Date+City?

Comment: There is error, it should be + instead of cbind. cbind should be used when you want to aggregate more variables (Sales and others). Now code is correct.